# Error 400 after sending correct data to imgur API

Tags: python, api, http, post, imgur

I am trying to implement a system where a Raspberry Pi takes a picture, gets uploaded to Imgur and then the link is sent to our slack. I am testing everything on a controlled enviroment first, before deploying it.

I used an online b64 encoding tool and then manually setup the POST request on Postman. The online tool outputs a string with some prefixes,so I manually remove it and everything is good. I get a 200 response code.

I then use the Requests python module to send the POST request. This is the code:

```
import base64
import requests
import json

with open('C:\\Users\\GoPato\\Desktop\\Fotojose.jpg', "rb") as imagen:
    img = base64.b64encode(imagen.read())
img = str(img)
print(type(img))
img = img[2:-1]
url = 'https://api.imgur.com/3/image'
headers = {'Authorization ': 'Bearer xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'}
payload = {'image':}
r = requests.post(url,data =json.dumps(payload), headers=headers)
print(r.status_code)
```

I replaced my *correct* token with that string of x's for my accounts security.

When I run that code, I get:

```
<class 'str'>
400
```

The resulting img is [this](https://pastebin.com/W0bwjB0N).

Thank you.

Edit: I forgot to put the content-type headers.

Comment: Any reason why you're not using the official [`imgurpython`](https://github.com/Imgur/imgurpython) module to do all the dirty work for you?

Comment: @zwer I didn't know that module existed. Thank you very much.